# How do I simulate ios on linux or any other alternatives for React native to work and test on ios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on react native and while I can code and test on android studio just fine, how I test the code on ios I don't own any apple product. Is there anyway I can simulate ios in linux?

Comment: you need XCode tools to build iOS app. so you need to have OSX installed first. you can try to install it on VM Ware, but not easy to find the image , maybe it's illegal

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple couple of thinks that you need and test.
you can't simulate IOS on linux but for test some utilities of macos as xcode you have the [darling hq proyect](https://www.darlinghq.org/) for run some macos apps on linux also you can't test directly macos(entire ecosystem no darling hq) but you can run a QEMU VirtulMachine with macos and a greate performace. here are a couple of sites you can check out

1. [youtube video fom linux tech tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATnpEOo3GJA)
2. [youtube video from the linux experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WgjQpm9VWE)

   1. [the github proyect that this use, yes a snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/sosumi/ubuntu) and [the other proyect](https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM)

---

also you can INSTALL MacOs directly on you machine if isn't to unpopular or to old; but this solution could be a pain in the ass for install and would have bad performance. but you can check this out [youtube video about this using linux from chris titus tech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUnVzJsINCI). this instalation is through [Opencore](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/)

---

### also there is a couple of other proyects for a QEMU VM you can research

and never buy a macos. exist funtional alternatives